# Is there an almost continuous function which cannot be almost equal to any other cont.function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there an almost continuous function which cannot be almost equal to any other continuous function?

Comment: To any other continous function different from itself ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-1 & x<0\\ 0 & x=0\\ 1 & x>0.\end{cases}$$ It's continuous except at $x=0$, and differs from any continuous function on a set of positive measure.

Comment: I understand thanks.